# 404 on category.php pagination

Tags: permalinks, pagination, 404-error

- My blog post page : **`mysite.com/blog`** => Work

  - Blog page pagination : **`mysite.com/blog/page/2`** =>
    Work
  - A category post url :   **`mysite.com/blog/cat`** => Work
  - A post url : **`mysite.com/blog/cat/postname`** => Work
  - A category post pagination url : **`mysite.com/blog/cat/page/2`** =>
    404 :-(
  - Permalink structure : `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`
  - Remove category base with Yoast: **ok**

Category.php :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar('page'); ?>
<div class="posts-list">
    <ul class="categs-list">
        <li class="<?php if(is_home()):?>current-cat<?php endif;?>"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_option('page_for_posts')); ?>" title="<?php _e('Voir tous les articles', 'fc'); ?>"><?php _e('Tous', 'fc'); ?></a></li>
        <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php pagination(); ?>
    <?php 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $category = get_the_category();
        get_template_part( 'content-category', $category[0]->slug );
    endwhile;
    ?>
    <?php pagination(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Function pagination() :

```
function pagination()
{

    if ( function_exists('wp_pagenavi') )
    {
        echo "<nav class='pagination'>";
            wp_pagenavi();
        echo "</nav>";
    }

}
```

Why do i get 404 with pagination ?

Edit: **`mysite.com/blog/cat/feed`** doesn't work either

Comment: Share some code with us. Other wise it is pretty tough to figure out your actual problem.

Comment: @the_dramatist I've updated my question. There's nothing more. It worked before I modify Permalink structure from `/%category%/%postname%/` to `/blog/%category%/%postname%/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58471/including-category-base-in-a-post-permalink-results-in-404) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121434/custom-rewrite-rules-for-feeds-of-custom-queries-query-var-query-strings-in-url) i was able to adapt the solution to my problem.

**Solution:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa58471_category_base' );
function wpa58471_category_base() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'blog/([^/]+)/page/(\d+)/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top' 
    );
    add_rewrite_rule( 
        'blog/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$',
        'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]', 
        'top' 
    );
}
```

Comment: 10x! saved me lots of time :)